# I have a list inside it there are tuples with names and marks of students i want to select studrnts with second highest marks

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

this is the list:

```
l1=[('arjun',21),
    ('arushi',22),
    ('aman',22),
    ('tanmai',23)]
```

and i have a program which will find out the second highest marks which is 22 (i somehow made it). Now i want to print out the names which correspond to the `marks = 22` and I'm unable to do it.
So basically for the above list the output should be

> arushi aman

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you've written so far that tries to extract 1st highest and 2nd highest marks, even if it is not yet working properly. You may find that [itemgetter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is helpful for your use case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @J_H the question is as follows Given the names and grades for each student in a class of  students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.

Note: If there are multiple students with the second lowest grade, order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

Comment: @J_H thanks a lot but i found out the solutions !

Answer (score 1):

with a list of tuples , you can find the second highest marks by creating another list of marks , converting it into a set and then get the second highest element

```py
l1=[('arjun',21),
    ('arushi',22),
    ('aman',22),
    ('tanmai',23)]

marks = []
for item in l1:
    marks.append(item[1])

marks = sorted(set(marks))
second_highest_marks = marks[1]


for item in l1:
    if(item[1]==second_highest_marks):
        print(item[0])
```

This code first sorts the list and then prints all the elements with the same marks as the second highest

if you are worried about the time complexity , then the python sort function is O(nlogn)

Comment: though sort happens faster here, you had to do a for loop and match it with the second highest value which takes O(n) complexity and also the reverse of the list is a linear operation which also takes O(n).

Comment: What if two students have highest marks? This code will fail right?

Comment: ohh i wasnt able to do the simple task of seperating the tuples from the list now seeing the code it makes it soo much more clear thanks a lot now i will be able to make a code myself where the names and grades need to be user input as well!!

Answer (score 0):

Track the names while you check for the second highest value.

```
l1=[('arjun',21), ('arushi',22), ('aman',22), ('tanmai',23)]

first_2_largest = [[[], 0], [[], 0]]

for mark in l1:
    if mark[1] == first_2_largest[0][1]:
        first_2_largest[0][0].append(mark[0])
    elif mark[1] == first_2_largest[1][1]:
        first_2_largest[1][0].append(mark[0])
    elif mark[1] > first_2_largest[0][1]:
        first_2_largest.insert(0, [[mark[0]], mark[1]])
        first_2_largest.pop()
    elif mark[1] > first_2_largest[1][1]:
        first_2_largest.pop()
        first_2_largest.append([[mark[0]], mark[1]])
        
print(', '.join(first_2_largest[-1][0]))
```

**Output**

```
arushi, aman
```

Also post your code/snippet along with your questions & errors, so that others can easily understand and help better.

Comment: i am kinda new on stack so idk how to post my snippet if you can help me with that it will be great , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Improving Akshat's answer.

```
l1=[('arjun',21),
    ('arushi',22),
    ('aman',22),
    ('tanmai',23)]

all_marks = list(set([x[1] for x in l1]))
sorted_marks = sorted(all_marks,reverse=True)

if len(sorted_marks) > 1:
    second_highest = sorted_marks[1]

    # Looping second highest scores
    names =[]
    for name, marks in filter(lambda x: x[1]== second_highest, l1):
        names.append(name)
    print(' '.join(names))
```

Shorter version

```
l1=[('arjun',21),
    ('arushi',22),
    ('aman',22),
    ('tanmai',23)]

sorted_marks = sorted(list(set([x[1] for x in l1])),reverse=True)

if len(sorted_marks) > 1:
    second_highest = sorted_marks[1]
    print(*list(map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x:x[1] == second_highest, l1))), sep=' ')
# else:
#     print('All students scored same marks')
```